# External CSS Not Working, possible syntax error?

Tags: html, css, syntax

I realize that this might be a duplicate but even looking at all the other posts I can't seem to figure it out. My CSS sheet:

```
h2 {
    text-align:center; 
    color:black; 
    font-family : Verdana, Arial, Tahoma, Calibri, sans-serif; 
}

h3 {
    text-align:center; 
    color:black; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    font-family : Verdana, Arial, Impact, Tahoma, sans-serif; 
}

p {
    font-family: Georgia, Times New Roman, Century, serif; 
    color:blue; 
    text-align:left; 
    font-size: 12px;
}

td {
    font-family: Bookman Old Style, Cooper Black, Garamond, Goudy Old Style, serif; 
    color: green; 
    text-align: left; 
    font-size: 12px;
}

a:link {
    color: red; 
    text-decoration: "none";
}

a:visited {
    color: teal; 
    text-decoration: "none" 
}

a:active {
    color: yellow; 
    text-decoration: "none"
}

a:hover {
    color: orange; 
    font-weight: underline;
}
```

My HTML page:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>TITLE GOES HERE</title>
<link rel=“stylesheet” type=“text/css” href=“base.css”>
  <style>
    body { 
      background-color: #ccffff;
      font-family: Geneva, Arial, Halvetica, sans-serif;                                
    }
    table, td {
      border:1px solid black;
    }
    table {
      width:100%;
    }
    th {
      height: 40px; 
      background-color: #ffffcc;
    }
  </style>             
</head>
```

The link isn't in the `<style>` tag but between the `head` tag so shouldn't it work? Even after removing the `style` tag nothing happens.

Comment: https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea will identify the problem

Comment: i think font family need double quotes " fonts " -- http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-family.asp

Comment: or may be not -- using http://csslint.net/ -- you have 1 warning here -- (Expected (normal | bold | bolder | lighter | 100 | 200 | 300 | 400 | 500 | 600 | 700 | 800 | 900 | inherit) but found 'underline'.
a:hover{color: orange; font-weight: underline;} 
All

8 lines 0 errors 1 warnings) -- so it should load ok. is the css file in the same folder as your index page?

Comment: There are a few issues that will break specific things in the CSS, the duplicate explains why the whole thing is ignored.

Comment: @Quentin -- do you actually see  ” in the OP's code? cause all i see is "

Comment: @Tasos — Yes, and so does the validator that I linked to in my first comment.

Comment: @Quentin -- try it on http://csslint.net/

Comment: @Tasos — Why? It's an HTML problem. That tool asks me to put some CSS in the box, not some HTML.

Comment: @Quentin  - i checked with validator -- Document checking completed. No errors or warnings to show.  at least csslint.net  shows you a warning

Comment: @Quentin -- sorry, you meant here (<link rel=“stylesheet” type=“text/css” href=“base.css”>) what a dipshit :))

Comment: https://www.evernote.com/l/AAMePlMd8CtIX6VczO8aO_N0rCgmHA-_Oss

Comment: @Tasos yes it is in the same folder